# js event for when statement becomes true inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

Ok I'm using the vimeo api and it provides my function with some data containing the percentage played of my video. I want to use this to find when the video finishes, and to 'turn the lights back on' then. Here is my code:

```
    function onplayProgress(data, id) {
$('#bottomtag').text(data.percent*100 + '% played');

    if ( data.percent == '1') {
$('body').animate({ backgroundColor: 'gray' }, 3000);
    }

}
```

The #bottomtag is just to debug, but it correctly shows the progress and eventually gets to 100% and stays there. So I can't understand why my animation is not happening. Am I being really dense? I feel like semantically there should be a 'when' not an 'if' but that doesn't exist.

=========EDIT=========

As pointed out by Zeta there is a Finish event that I could use. However I want my 'lights' to go up at 99% played and I also want to know why my code isn't working. I've tried ~

`if ( data.percent == '0.990')`

~ and it still isn't working. In regards to the calling of this function it is hooked to the Vimeo api as such:

`player.addEvent('playProgress', onplayProgress`);

Comment: It seems like that `onplayProgress()` function is going to be called multiple times, rather than just a single time, so using an `if` statement should be correct. However, having no familiarity with the API you're using, I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) provides a `finish` event. Use this instead to check whether your video has finished playing.

#### Edit: How can I light up the lights after 99%?

This is a little bit trickier, however, still easy to achieve:

```
function onplayProgress(data, id) {
    $('#bottomtag').text(data.percent*100 + '% played');
    if ( data.percent >= 0.990 && $('body').data("has-been-animated") !== true) {
        $('body').animate({ backgroundColor: 'gray' }, 3000);
        $('body').data("has-been-animated",true);
    }
}
```

Comment: lol I must have missed it. I thought it was strange it wasn't there. However I still want to understand why my code is not working. I've decided to up the lights as the credits roll I.E. (data.percent == '0.990')

Comment: Don't you ever use a string comparison on a number. That poor thing :(. Also equality tests on floating numbers are tricky, use `data.percent >= 0.990` and use a separate variable to check whether you already animated the background already.

Comment: Thanks for going into detail, now I've learnt it. I promise never to do that to numbers ever again :}

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `data.percent = '1.00'` (as a string) then your if will fail because `'1' != '1.00'`

Comment: lol just saw the first answer. `finish` does sound rather more appropriate :)

Comment: You should not only point to the errors, but also try to give a solution. How could he solve this problem without `finish`? Apparently OP isn't aware of the difference between string and number comparison in JavaScript. Try to point this out to improve your answer :).

Comment: Cheers I see your point, I'll add a bit more explanation next time :) Incidental is your solution using `$('body').data("has-been-animated")` not a little vulnerable if animations on the body have already been performed? perhaps better to use a specific boolean? (I would comment on your answer but I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: `$('body').data("has-been-animated")` will be `undefined`, except after the condition has been triggered. Then `$('body').data("has-been-animated")` will be `true`, and thus-by the condition will be false.

Comment: ahh I see my bad. I'd never seen jQ's data()

Comment: Actually I do a fade to a black background on the play event. So I changed the meaning of the data to 'lightsup' and set it false on the play event animation.